# In wordpress where is the code that differentiates between categories and standard pages?

Tags: wordpress

This is a question for Wordpress experts:

Where, in the Wordpress machine, is the code that decides whether to route a query to the standard page or to a category? Does it try to match specific strings in the URL looking for categories and then, if it doesn't get a match, default to the code that looks for the page in the wp_posts table?

This is something I have been wondering about for a while but I have found it difficult trying to trace the path of the query through the system.

Thanks for any insights you can give!

Comment: You may find this site helpful: https://wphierarchy.com. There are also several related links from there that dig into how routing works in WordPress.

Comment: ooh, that's very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for this you can use to hook in a page or a category.

```
function is_category( $category = '' ) {
}

function is_page( $page = '' ) {
}
```

$category / $page can be ID, name, slug or array

Comment: ok that's great - I will check out those functions. Thanks!